# Changing div properties

Tags: php, html, css

```
<div class="name" style="top:208px; left: 140px;">
```

This works just fine but I want to change the style properties according to variables. If someone could write the correct syntax because mine won't work (I assume it has something to do with quotations..)

```
<div class="name" style="top:<?php echo $top?>px; left: <?php echo $left?>px;">
```

Comment: If you haven't disabled shorthand notation, `<?php echo /*something*/?>` can also be written as `<?=/*something*/?>`. PS: Why no semicolon at the end of your echos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should close the echo's with `;` like down here.

```
<div class="name" style="top:<?php echo $top;?>px; left: <?php echo $left;?>px;">
```

Comment: thanks for the answers.. it works with or without `;`. The problem was that I got the values for top and left from POST method so I had to convert it to number, instead of just using it like that

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="name" style="top:<?php echo $top; ?>px; left: <?php echo $left; ?>px;">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$top=200;
$left=50;

?>

<div class="name" style="top:<?php echo $top?>px; left:<?php echo $left?>px;"></div>
```

i think the problem ar the space in after "left: 200" or the char ";" missing or the `</div>` tag missing.